# Error connecting to AWS RDS Oracle Service Instance

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, sqlplus, amazon-rds

I have spun up an aws rds instance for Oracle 11g db. I have also configured VPC & Security Groups.

Now I'm trying to connect to the db using

```
sqlplus64 'dbuser@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dbinstancedns) (PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sidofdb)))'
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 & have set up 'SQLPlus64' using instructions on [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client)

I'm getting response as:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jan 19 10:09:23 2018
Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

I'm entering the correct password, DB instance is running & Security group is setup correctly.

What is the problem here?

Comment: For diagnostics, check the availability of port 1521 on the DBMS host `telnet binstancedns 1521`

Comment: Your computer with UBUNTU is located in the cloud AWS EC2?

Comment: Thanks @DmitryDemin, it had to do with VPC issues. Got it resolved with few tweaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb question, but are you sure the host is reachable?
Try using netcat to connect to that host to pot 1521, it may be that the DB is not public or the otherway around the DNS may be valid but not exposing the IP you expect.
You can also check the DNS and compare the returning IP to what you expect to have, private or public